# How could I read secure value from cookie in spring?

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, spring-boot, cookies

How could I read a secure and HttpOnly value from cookie in spring?

I save JWT token in a secure and HttpOnly value in cookie but I can't get it from `HttpServletRequest`.

I send request with postman and if i delete secure from cookie, it works fine but when I send it with cookie, I can't access it!

This is cookie's value:

```
token=eyJhbGciOiJIUzUxMiJ9.eyJzdWIiOiIxIiwiaWF0IjoxNTQzMDgzMzc2LCJleHAiOjE1NDM2ODgxNzZ9.8IWh2HO7aVoxuVNUWCIhV1AeHvmTD5GyvopJGQFv9fgrYNBY8ZzbeapikTRpPNG3oDSWOvjbLU-lpWx7MWAYRw; path=/; domain=localhost; Secure; HttpOnly; Expires=Tue, 19 Jan 2038 03:14:07 GMT;
```

I create cookie with this code:

```
Cookie cookie = new Cookie(jwtTokenName, generateToken(authentication));
cookie.setPath("/");
cookie.setHttpOnly(true);
cookie.setSecure(true);
response.addCookie(cookie);
```

and it's content on applications.yml:

```
server:
  port: 8181
  servlet:
    session:
      cookie:
        secure: true
app:
  jwtSecret: JWTSuperSecretKey
  jwtExpirationInMs: 604800000
  jwtTokenName: token
```

Comment: Do you use https? If you don't, since the Secure flag is set, the browser won't send it: that's the point of the secure flag.

Comment: No, It's on HTTP. I use postman for send request; Does it only send on HTTPS?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Secure_cookie

Comment: What are you *trying* to do? Why do you need these two flags?

Comment: It's done. I try to save JWT token in cookie and then get it, and I enabled secure in local development.

Answer (score 0):

When you add "secure" to your HTTP Header, it indicates that the Cookie should be transmitted over Secured channels only, using HTTPS.

That is the possible reason why you face problems.

If you have the required certificate or authenticated tokens, you can set them at HTTP headers.

Use clients like Insomnia or Advanced REST Client which provide you these options.